# android unit test mockito do not work natural

Tags: java, android, mockito

sometimes i use mockito like to:

```
Mockito.doReturn("1").when(Mockito.spy(new ArrayList<String>()))).get(0);
```

I get "1" when I write code:

```
spylist.get(0);
```

In My Android APP unit test, i mock a ViewModel class: mockViewModel.and i want to spy it and add a stub:

```
MyViewModel spyViewModel = spy(mockViewModel);
doReturn(false).when(spyViewModel).getResult();
```

when I call getResult method, i get use is wrong

```
true
```

so, how I can get a correct result when I use mockito 'doReturn' ?

I tried to debug in Android Studio, But I can know how to find error because mockito use some libs to generate classes file...

Comment: First of all, you have a misconception about `spy`. You normally use that to call real methods, not to mock them (although that works as well). Now to your issue: what is `mockViewModel`? If that is a real mock like `Mockito.mock(ViewModel.class);` then your approach misses the "configuration" of the mock and you wouldn't need a spy. Just use `doReturn(false).when(mockViewModel).getResult();`

Comment: post the complete code

Comment: tks, i use kotin and myviewmodel class is final default...